# difference between UNTIL and BEFORE

Tags: sentence-construction

I searched the internet for it and I found this.

Event-1 UNTIL Event-2
Event-1 continues up to the time when Event-2 begins.
Event-1 BEFORE Event-2
Event-1 occurs prior to the time when Event-2 begins.

So, to make sure that I understand this fully, I made 2 right sentences and 2 wrong sentences. And I'd like to know if I've done a good job.

2 right sentences

> Until you called me, I had been studying for about 3 hours.
>
> Before you called me, I'd visited a store and bought some foods.

2 wrong sentences.

> Until you called me, I'd visited a store and bought some foods.
>
> Before you called me, I had been studying for about 3 hours.

Comment: This question is about until and after, but it might also be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41444/9161

Comment: "Foods" here is not exactly *wrong*, but it's certainly odd and probably not really what you want, since it draws extra attention to the idea of buying a certain number of different food types. "Food" is the usual usage, lumping all the different types of food together and emphasizing instead the overall quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of your 4 sentences, three are correct. The only one that is **not correct** is:

> Until you called me, I'd visited a store and bought some foods.

*Until* is used for to specify a duration going on up to the point specified by what follows *until*.

In the following sentence, the action of *studying for about 3 hours* had been going on up to the point where the speakers was called.

> Until you called me, I had been studying for about 3 hours.

The same sentence, but with *before*, is also correct, but there is a difference in meaning. The studying here also took about 3 hours, but it had already stopped at the moment that the speaker was called. So, the caller did not interrupt or stop the person studying:

> Before you called me, I had been studying for about 3 hours.

The third correct sentence is:

> Before you called me, I'd visited a store and bought some foods.

The action was completed before the speaker was called. This is the reason that *until* cannot be used here, because that would mean the action had been going on up to the point where the person was called. The past perfect *had visited* here implies that the speaker had already finished the action of going to the store to buy food.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a time problem.  We always used before when the things have not happen. but until always told what was happened already.